# Do I need a custom authorizer in API Gateway when using AWS Cognito JWT tokens for authentication?

Tags: aws-lambda, jwt, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

AWS writes about a custom authorizer function for implementing implement various authorization strategies, such as JSON Web Token (JWT) verification and OAuth provider callout: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html

There is also something called AWS_IAM.

Can I use AWS_IAM if I am using AWS Cognito JWT tokens for authentication? Or do I need to create a custom authorizer?

Comment: Yes , if you are using AWS cognito jwt tokens for authentication , then after authentication you would be able to access all the resources which you have defined in the corresponding role of your userpool . And for the API gateway ,just use authorizer as `aws_iam`  so that your API is only accessible to authenticated users.And you don't need a custom authorizer for this very purpose.

Comment: @Rohan Seth, are you suggesting that you can use an aws_iam authorization method using Cognito issued JWTs? My understanding is that when using a Cognito issued JWT for authorization, you either use Cognito itself to validate the token, or set up a Custom Authorizer in Lambda.